# Reloading PBKeyBindings.dict while Xcode is running

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts, key-bindings

I am creating my Xcode key bindings by editing `PBKeyBindings.dict`, since this seems to be the way to create commands that are sequences of method calls. This works fine, but one must reload Xcode to have the changes take effect. Is there some way to prod Xcode into reloading this file as it is running?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to touch any dictionary files. You can edit Xcode's key bindings in its Preferences window, and apply any changes you make there immediately by clicking the “Apply” button.

Comment: Which version of Xcode is this? (This was not my experience at the time; no UI for mapping keys to sequences of operations,so PBKeyBindings.dict seemed the only way -- and worse yet that file only gets checked if you use the standard key bindings set, which are not editable in the UI, so PBKeyBindings.dict has to be manually edited for any change.)

Comment: It was introduced in Project Builder back in 2002, almost a year before they changed the name to Xcode: http://developer.apple.com/tools/xcode/dec2002PBReleaseNotes.html